# Move / backup Netbeans FTP profiles

Tags: netbeans, ftp

Trying to figure out how to transfer / back remote connections in netbeans. I have over 100 that I would like to move to a backup computer. Recreating every one of them would be extremely time intensive. I cannot find any way to export the remote profiles and I haven't been able to find the profiles in the .netbeans directory on the local computer.

Is there a file, or any method that would allow moving or backing up the FTP profiles.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The path on Windows would be: 
user\.netbeans\6.7\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\php\project\RemoteConnections

Comment: Mac: `/Users/`user`/Library/Application Support/NetBeans/8.0.1/config/Preferences/org/netbeans/modules/php/project/RemoteConnections`

Comment: What is "user.netbeans"? No file system has file paths that start like that. This answer is not correct on any platform.

Answer (score 25):

The location changed in Netbeans 7.2.  The path is the same except `AppData\Roaming` instead of `AppData\Local`.

If you are setting up a new windows machine to run Netbeans, you need to first create a dummy remote ftp connection so Netbeans will create the last folder in this file path.  Place the `.properties` files here and then restart Netbeans.

`C:\Users\[windowsUsername]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.2.1\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\php\project\RemoteConnections`

Comment: Appreciate the update. I am still happy with 7.1.1, but good to know if I upgrade again in the future.

Comment: As of version 8.0 and 8.1, this path is still the same - with the obvious version number difference.  Note that it does not include the saved passwords though.

Comment: This is the answer that should be accepted, it actually gives the file path, at least on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10:

C:\Users\ (***username***) \AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\ (***netbeans_version***) \config\Preferences\org\netbeans\modules\php\project\RemoteConnections